# Multiple arguments seperated with a comma in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have the following code for my discord bot, it's basically an image manipulation command but I don't know how to make 2 arguments seperated by a comma, in the old discord.py I just would have used "message.content.split(",")", but it seems like it doesn't work anymore in discord.py rewrite, any suggestions or ideas on how to do this?
Code:

```
async def topone(ctx, *, frstInput = "Tartarus", scndInput = "riot"):
    for attachment in ctx.message.attachments:

        await attachment.save("toponeimg.png")
        back_im = Image.open("toponetemplate.png")
        imre = Image.open("toponeimg.png")
        imre_resize = imre.resize((207, 116))
        back_im.paste((imre_resize), (38, 29))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(back_im)
        imgFont = ImageFont.truetype("C:/Users/Flippy/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Montserrat-Semibold.ttf", 34)
        imgFont2 = ImageFont.truetype("C:/Users/Flippy/AppData/Local/Microsoft/Windows/Fonts/Montserrat-Semibold.ttf", 24,)


        draw.text((318, 74), frstInput, (0, 0, 0), font=imgFont, anchor="ls")
        # 'scndInput' is the argument I want to specify after a command, like "!topone Arg1, Arg2"
        draw.text((262, 112), scndInput, (74, 74, 74), font=imgFont2, anchor="ls")


        back_im.save("follow_hourly_bbc_on_twitter.png", quality=68)
        await ctx.send(file = discord.File("follow_hourly_bbc_on_twitter.png"))
        return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take all the text as a single string and then split it by the comma

```py
async def topone(ctx, *, content):
    first_input, second_input = content.split(",")
    ...
```